# Limit the number of lines or words using regex in Google forms

Tags: regex, string, validation, google-forms

Does anybody know any regex to restrict a string to specified number of lines and words for data validation of a field in google forms?

I have already tried the following expression

```
^(?:\b\w+\b[\s\r\n]*){1,250}$
```

That would limit to 250 words over multiple lines.

but it is not working when there is any special character in the string.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `[\s\r\n]` matches any whitespace chars only. You may use `\W` to match any non-word char:

```
^\w+(?:\W+\w+){0,249}$
       ^^
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `(?:\W+\w+){0,249}` - 0 to 249 (1 to 250 in total) sequences of:

  - `\W+` - 1+ non-word chars
  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars (that is, words separated with 1+ symbol, whitespace or punctuation)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that worked for words but struggling to get the line restriction regex

Comment: @SAISUDHEER: What do you mean by line restriction? Could you please update the *question* rather than adding requirements via comments? Note that `\W` matches line breaks, and if you do not want that, use `[^\w\n\r]`.